Convergence of the sequence $\frac{3 + \sqrt{n}}{2n - \sqrt{n}}$ with epsilon delta
How do I prove that this sequence converges:
$$
x_n = \frac{3 + \sqrt{n}}{2n - \sqrt{n}}
$$
I need to use epsilon delta definition of convergence. I have tried making an upper bound numerator, but it does not work.

Please edit your post to show your attempts. First of all, if you want to apply the epsilon-delta definition (which you should recall in your post), you have to formulate a guess for the value of the limit. Hint

Try finding a lower bound for the denominator instead. Can you drop the $-\sqrt{n}$ term?

Try to find some constants $a,b>0$ such that $3+\sqrt n\le a\sqrt n$ and $2n-\sqrt n\ge bn$.

If you rationalize the denominator, you get $x_n = \frac{2n\sqrt{n} + 7n + 3\sqrt{n}}{4n^2 - n}$.  Does that help?

We may restrict to $n>100$, and in this case $3+\sqrt n< 2024\sqrt n$, and $2n-\sqrt n>n$, always be that generous (when it doesn't matter, we do not pay for the numerator)! This implies$$0\le \frac{3+\sqrt n}{2n-\sqrt n}<\frac {2024\sqrt n}{n}\qquad\dots$$

$$0<\frac{3+\sqrt n}{2n-\sqrt n}\leq\frac{3+\sqrt n}{n}\leq\frac{2\sqrt n}{n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt n},\quad \forall n\geq9.$$

More simply, what I had in mind in my previous comment was: ($\forall n\in\Bbb N$): $$0\le\frac{3+\sqrt n}{2n-\sqrt n}\le\frac{4\sqrt n}n.$$

First observe that for $n \ge 1 \implies n \ge \sqrt{n}\implies 2n - \sqrt{n} \ge n\implies \dfrac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}} \le \dfrac{3+\sqrt{n}}{n}=\dfrac{3}{n} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus for a given $\epsilon > 0$, and let $N$ be a positive integer such that $N \ge \text{max}\left(\dfrac{6}{\epsilon}, \dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2}\right)$, then if $n \ge N \implies a_n = \dfrac{3}{n}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \dfrac{3}{\dfrac{6}{\epsilon}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2}}}=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$. This shows that $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
